# Far-manager в качестве core.editor для Git

Tags: windows, git, far-manager

Пытаюсь установить Far-manager редактором для коммитов в Git:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Far Manager/Far.exe' -e"
```

После выполнения `git commit` появляется пустая строка, куда можно вводить текст, Enter переводит указатель курсора на новую строку, а вот как отправить напечатанный текст в качестве комментария к коммиту? Выйти из "пустой строки" получается только нажатием Ctrl+C, после чего, коммит, естественно, не выполняется.

Работаю в git bash в Windows 8 (Git for Windows).

**Upd**:
Проверил запуск команды из cmd.exe:

> "C:/Program Files/Far Manager/Far.exe" -e Readme.txt

Все отлично работает: запускается Фар в режиме редактирования файла, после нажатия F2 изменения записываются.

Проверил то же самое из git bash:

$ "C:/Program Files/Far Manager/Far.exe" -e Readme.txt

Курсор опустился на одну строку, мигает, можно писать текст, вот только сохранить изменения хоть куда-нибудь невозможно, помогает только Ctrl+C

Comment: А как реагирует на 'q' и на 'F1-F12' клавиши?

Comment: При нажатии на любой цифробуквенный символ он пишется в консоли, при нажатии F1,F2,F3,F4 пишется, соответственно, P,Q,R,S, нажимая на F5-F12 не происходит вообще ничего.

Comment: Ctrl + d , маловероятно, конечно,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашел в оф. репозитории Git for Windows: [github.com/git-for-windows/git/...](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ#some-native-console-programs-dont-work-when-run-from-git-bash-how-to-fix-it). Far Manager не запускается в mintty-терминале, который используется в git bash. Советы, как объеденить Far-Manager и Git for Windows есть в сылке выше, я же решил не заморачиваться, а использовать встроеный в Windows Notepad.exe :)

С версии Git for Windows 2.5.3+:

```
$ git config --global core.editor notepad
$ git config --global format.commitMessageColumns 72
```

Answer (score 0):

Чисто в качестве предположения (сам не пользовал) ... Существует версия [Midnight Commander для Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcwin32/). Если и в этой сборке редактор `mcedit` идет отдельной программой - думаю, можно попробовать его запускать, и возможно даже получится.

**Add:** Ради интереса проверил, редактор нормально запускается, вот так: `mc -e файл`

Answer (score 0):

Создать `bat`-файл `ed.bat`, в котором прописать:

```
"C:/Program Files/Far Manager/Far.exe" -e %1
```

и затем

```
git config --global core.editor "path to file/ed.bat"
```